# Python circles in a 1x1 square not overlapping or outside the square

Tags: python, python-3.x

So what I have to do is create 50 circles wich are not overlapping or outside a square (0,0) to (1,1) here is my code so far:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([.1, .1, .8, .8], axisbg = 'Violet', aspect = 'equal')
clist = []

def overlap(c1, c2):
    distance = ((c1.center[0] - c2.center[0])**2 + (c1.center[0] - c2.center[0])**2)**0.5
    return distance < c1.radius + c2.radius

for i in range(1000):
    x = np.random.rand(1)
    y = np.random.rand(1)
    c = Circle(xy=(x, y), radius = 0.05, fc = 'Blue', ec = 'DarkBlue', lw = 1.5)
    if x - 0.05 >= 0.0:
        if x + 0.05 <= 1.0:
            if y - 0.05 >= 0.0:
                if y + 0.05 <= 1.0:
                    if len(clist) == 0:
                        clist.append(c)
                        ax.add_patch(c)
                    else:
                        for j in range(len(clist)):
                            if overlap(c, clist[j]) == True:
                                break
                            if j == len(clist) - 1:
                                if overlap(c, clist) == False:
                                    clist.append(c)
                                    ax.add_atch(c)
    if len(clist) == 50:
        break

ax.autoscale()
```

If I would print my list I would get the following:

```
[<matplotlib.patches.Circle object at 0x07E5F3D0>]
```

So when I run my code this error occurs:

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-35-48e3a2854e8e> in <module>()
     24                                 break
     25                             if j == len(clist) - 1:
---> 26                                 if overlap(c, clist) == False:
     27                                     clist.append(c)
     28                                     ax.add_atch(c)

<ipython-input-35-48e3a2854e8e> in overlap(c1, c2)
      4 
      5 def overlap(c1, c2):
----> 6     distance = ((c1.center[0] - c2.center[0])**2 + (c1.center[0] -     c2.center[0])**2)**0.5
      7     return distance < c1.radius + c2.radius
      8 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'center'
```

So the mistake is that the circle is stored correctly in the list, but I have seen other people doing it this way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of python are you using? You have the `python-2.7` tag and the `python-3.x` tag.

Comment: I'm using python 3.5

Comment: Is using `numpy` a requirement here? I don't see why you are calling `np.random.rand` for this task. If you continue to use `numpy`, you should modify your code to get both x and y coordinates at the same time. Also, regardless, once you have a random number in [0,1), you can multiply it by the length of the range to scale it, and add it to the starting point (the radius) to make sure it fits in the right box. That would eliminate your 4 if statements to check valid positioning.

Comment: Yes the assignment said we had to use np.random.rand.

Comment: You should keep the question, just in case can be useful for someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `c` as a `Circle` with this code:

```
c = Circle(xy=(x, y), radius = 0.05, fc = 'Blue', ec = 'DarkBlue', lw = 1.5)
```

You are eventually executing this code with `clist`:

```
clist.append(c)
```

Clearly, one is a Circle, and the other is a list.

You later execute this code:

```
if overlap(c, clist[j]) == True:
```

Showing that `clist[j]` is a circle, as expected.

Then, you do this:

```
if overlap(c, clist) == False:
```

You can't do that. `clist` is a list, not a `Circle`. You have to index it, like `clist[j]` or whatever.

Comment: So this worked the error is gone! Thank you! But now I've only got between 8-11 circles every time i run the code and sometimes they still overlap.

Comment: Time for a new question. I'd suggest writing a function to return a valid circle (i.e., within 0.05..0.95 x,y). Then you can focus on collision avoidance. Also, look at the `else` keyword on the `for` loop. I think you want that for your innermost check.